# why is MathJax adding a frame around text in HTML which has no math indicators around it?

Tags: mathjax

This is an HTML generated by htlatex. When I use Mathjax, the HTML, which has no math in it, shows completely different. MathJax adds a frame around the text in the body of the HTML.

When I remove MathJax, the frame is gone.

Here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> <title></title> 
<meta charset="UTF-8" /> 

<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script> 

</head>

<body>

&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;this&#x00A0;is&#x00A0;verbatim

&#x00A0;<br />&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;\begin{foo}
&#x00A0;<br />&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;test
&#x00A0;<br />&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;\end{foo}
&#x00A0;<br />&#x00A0;&#x00A0;

</body> 
</html>
```

Here is the screen output on firefox:

[image]

Now when I remove MathJax from the HTML head, this is the output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> <title></title> 
<meta charset="UTF-8" /> 

</head>

<body>

&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;this&#x00A0;is&#x00A0;verbatim

&#x00A0;<br />&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;\begin{foo}
&#x00A0;<br />&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;test
&#x00A0;<br />&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;\end{foo}
&#x00A0;<br />&#x00A0;&#x00A0;

</body> 
</html>
```

and the HTML looks like

[image]

Fyi, the original latex file `foo.tex` used to generate the above HTML is

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{document}

  \begin{verbatim}
     this is verbatim
    \begin{foo}    
         test  
    \end{foo}
  \end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Was compiled using the command

```
htlatex foo.tex "t.cfg"
```

where `t.cfg` is

```
\Preamble{}


\Configure{VERSION}{}
\Configure{DOCTYPE}{\HCode{<!DOCTYPE html>\Hnewline}}

\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{<html>\Hnewline}}{\HCode{\Hnewline</html>}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<meta charset="UTF-8" />\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="\expandafter\csname aa:CssFile\endcsname" />\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<script type="text/javascript"\Hnewline 
src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"\Hnewline
></script>\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<style type="text/css">\Hnewline
  .MathJax_MathML {text-indent: 0;}\Hnewline
</style>\Hnewline}
}    

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

**question is**  why is loading Mathjax causes a frame put around the text shown and center it in middle of the page?

Comment: Your HTML is very weird... why are you using forced spacing instead of putting the code in a `<pre>` (or other element with preformatted text CSS property) for normal code view? Also, text doesn't go straight into the `body` tag, put it in a `div` or `p`, first. I strongly suspect MathJax is tripping over bad HTML in this case.

Comment: well, I can show you MathJax works just fine, as long as the output isn't insane: http://jsfiddle.net/HPDDn -- I use MathJax a lot myself (as well as XeLaTeX), so I'd recommend to not rely on htlatex. What is the underlying thing you're trying to achieve? (so that we don't solve an XY problem)

Comment: yeah, the "converting LaTeX to HTML" step is usually the problem, because TeX to HTML converters are really, really bad (still). It's usually actually much easier to just convert it yourself by adding the necessary `<p>...</p>` and `<p>\[...\]</p>` in your file. The HTML that htlatex is generating for you is extremely bad HTML.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also realise I've not actually answered your question, which is pretty lousy of me: MathJax will show plain text in a framed box if there's LaTeX code that it doesn't know how to convert: MathJax will not load all possible packages by default, so for a fair number of them you will need to set up the MathJax config object first, see http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html for which ones you can load.

For instance, http://jsfiddle.net/HPDDn/1/ shows two MathJax blocks, one that it knows how to convert, the other framed as plain text because it has no idea what `verbatim` is.

Comment: This seems to be correct:-) I must say I thought it only looked for tex inside the configurable  math and display math delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is unrelated to the spacing, you get the same frame from

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> <title></title> 
<meta charset="UTF-8" /> 

<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script> 

</head>

<body>

\begin{foo}
test
\end{foo}

</body> 
</html>
```

You can configure mathjax not to look at certain elements or just wrap the text in pre which mathjax ignores by default.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> <title></title> 
<meta charset="UTF-8" /> 

<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script> 

</head>

<body>

<pre>
\begin{foo}
test
\end{foo}
</pre>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).